# Binding functions to instances of React function components

Tags: reactjs

I found this code snippet from https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html that binds a function to specific instances of a React component:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

Can I do something similar using function components instead?

I've tried this method in a function component (moving `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` out of the constructor), but `this` (in the statement) returned undefined instead of the function component.

Comment: You just declare it as a function inside your functional component and refer to it like that. so `const handleClick = useCallback(() => { /* do stuff */}, []);` and `onClick={handleClick}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding methods in React isn't doing what it seems like you think it's doing.

`this.someMethod.bind(this)` was for binding the method to the class (not the child component), so the method has access to props and state.

When we got class properties, that wasn't necessary anymore (methods using arrow function syntax).

With function components, it's also completely irrelevant, because there's no scope issue when your function definition and use are in the same functional component.

So these three all do the same thing:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick () {
    console.log('clicked')
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => { console.log('clicked') }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
  }
}

const Foo = () => {
  const handleClick = () => { console.log('clicked') }
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
}
```